# Google Analytics Site Speed - iOS not being sampled

Tags: google-analytics, performance, page-speed

I'm looking at a breakdown of site speed by operating system in Google Analytics to get a sense of mobile vs desktop load times.  The problem is that it looks like GA doesn't really collect speed sample data from iOS?  Is this a known limitation with GA or something unique to this site?

See image:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari does not support the W3C Navigation Timing API, which is what I'd guess Google Analytics is using for the site speed data. The Mac results you're seeing could be from other browsers being used on that OS.

There is a petition somewhere to try and get Apple to support this standard, since they're [the only major browser that doesn't](http://caniuse.com/nav-timing).

Answer (score 0):

Its not just your site.  Google Analytics reports the same thing for one of my sites:

[image]

It also looks like it isn't sampling enough data points to be useful.   There is way to much noise if I go to the motion chart to graph history by device type.  Even the "Windows" line (yellow) which has the most data is extremely spiky:

[image]

Comment: ok thanks. but any explanation as to why?